# Javascript - Looping through custom tag

Tags: javascript, html

Using javascript, how can I loop through a custom tag and display the results WITHOUT having to press a button?

My javascript:

```
function a(){           
    var m=document.getElementsByTagName('myselect');
    for (var i = 0; i<m.length; i++)
         document.getElementById('divid').innerHTML  = m[i].value;                                      
}
```

My html:

```
  <myselect>
     <option> a </option>
     <option> b </option>
     <option> c </option>
   </myselect>
```

Right now, I can't get the custom tag and I cant display the information unless I define `<select>` tags instead of my custom tag. And even then, I have to press an input button   plus my javascript doesnt loop through all the elements, but the current selected element.

P.S. the reason Im using myselect, is because I dont want to show a dropdown on my html. Is there any other way that I could get the information?

Comment: why are you trying to make up an HTML tag? use `select`, give it an id of `"myselect"` and use `document.getElementById('myselect');` what are you trying to do?

Comment: _myselect_ is not an HTML tag and thus you should not use it in your HTML

Comment: @EricLemos I dont want to show a dropdown on my html. Is there any other way that I could get the information?

Comment: I just posted an answer but wait... Are you saying you don't want the things in the <option> tags (the a, b and c) to actually be shown on the page? Or do you want them to be shown on the page?

Comment: @Keeleon I dont want to show them on the page. Im just using a macro that turns info into dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define your myselect tag as a normal select tag and give it an id like so:

```
<select id="myselect">
```

Then in the body tag call the function with the onload attribute:

```
<body onload="a()">
```

Then in your javascript change getElementByTagName to getElementById like so:

```
ar m=document.getElementsById('myselect');
```

See if that works for you. I didn't test it out but that's the gist of it. I would also advise using jQuery

Comment: Also Im using a CMS, I cant just do `<body onload="a()">`, since `<body>` is define in master

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer then Jeff. If you don't want a drop down on the page, do you want the stuff in the option tags shown on the page at all? If so you can just use divs or spans and get the inner html of them.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented out you shouldn't use custom tags because the result will no longer be a valid HTML.

Second you use `m[i].value` instead of `m.options[i].value` which seems to give you currently selected element.

Third - not sure what you mean by *get the information* but it seems that you're trying to keep some info in your HTML document. A better way of doing that would be storing it in a JavaScript Array:

```
var values = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

If you really need your info to be part of HTML DOM and it needs to be a select you could come up with something like

```
<select style="display: none;"> etc...
```

That would be very strange, but no one would see it.